# limiting circles to a specific radius

Tags: arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript, circle

I am new to ArcGIS javascript api and I have created a map which allows users to draw circle geometries. I just want to limit the functionality so that the radius is specified at 10000km.

This is the code at the moment:

```
$('#circle').click(function () {
        clearPreviousSearch();
        map.disableMapNavigation();
        $('#run').fadeOut();
        buttonclickvalue = 'circle';
        drawToolbar.activate(esri.toolbars.Draw.CIRCLE);

    });
```

And I've amended it to this:

```
$('#circle').click(function (e) {
        var radius = map.extent.getWidth() / 10;
        radius : radius
        clearPreviousSearch();
        map.disableMapNavigation();
        $('#run').fadeOut();
        buttonclickvalue = 'circle';
        drawToolbar.activate(esri.toolbars.Draw.CIRCLE);

    });
```

Can anyone possibly help/give me some pointers to try and remedy?

Answer (score 1):

here is a sample script for drawing a cirlce on a specified radius.

```js
var circleSymb = new SimpleFillSymbol(
        SimpleFillSymbol.STYLE_NULL,
        new SimpleLineSymbol(
        SimpleLineSymbol.STYLE_SHORTDASHDOTDOT,
        new Color([105, 105, 105]),
        2 
       ), new Color([255, 255, 0, 0.25])
      );
        var circle;

    //when the map is clicked create a buffer around the click point of the specified distance.       

    map.on("click", function(evt){ 
        circle = new Circle({
        center: evt.mapPoint,
        geodesic: true,
        radius: 5,
        radiusUnit: "esriMiles"
       });
          map.graphics.clear();
          map.infoWindow.hide();
          var graphic = new Graphic(circle, circleSymb);
          map.graphics.add(graphic);
```